# How to get the qualified class name of generic type in annotation processing?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I have an interface like this:

```
interface MyInterface<V>{

}
```

and all of my annotated classes with `@MyAnnotation` implement this interface in different ways, for example.

```
//first way
Class1 implement MyInterface<SomeClass>
//second way
AbstractClass<V> implement MyInterface<V>
Class2 extends  AbstractClass<SomeClass>
//third way    
ConcreteClass implement MyInterface<SomeClass>
Class3 extends ConcreteClass
```

Well, I have `TypeElement`s of class 1,2 and 3 and I want to find qualified name of type variable `V`.

I tried this but it returns `V` instead of `SomeClass`.

```
TypeElement class1 = ...
while(reachToMyInterface){
for (TypeMirror m : ((DeclaredType) class1.asType()).getTypeArguments()) {
      print(m.toString()) // prints V
  }
  class1 = getItsSuperClass();
}
```

Edit:
Also this approach has same problem:

```
 for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Haha.class)) {
            if (element instanceof TypeElement) {
                TypeElement te = (TypeElement) element;
                TypeElement currentType = te;
                while(currentType!=null){
                for (TypeMirror typeMirror : currentType .getInterfaces()) {
                  if (typeMirror instanceof DeclaredType) {
                       DeclaredType dclt = (DeclaredType) typeMirror;
                      for (TypeMirror argument : dclt.getTypeArguments()) {
                        print(argument);
                      }
                   }
                }
                currentType = getSuperClass(currentType);                   
              }
}
private TypeElement getSuperClass(TypeElement typeElement) {
        if (!(typeElement.getSuperclass() instanceof DeclaredType)) return null;
        DeclaredType declaredAncestor = (DeclaredType) typeElement.getSuperclass();

        return (TypeElement) declaredAncestor.asElement();
    }
```

Comment: @JornVernee if `MyInterface` has a method `void foo(V bar)` then is it possible to get `MyClass` ? I still get confused with second way because it's possible that Class2  is not overriding `foo`

Comment: @JornVernee annotation processing happens at compile time, not runtime. And your statement is false for runtime, also. Instance types are erased, but  type bounds in classes, methods and fields are kept. Querying this information is a very advanced subject tho. It's discussed here: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's painful, but it can be done.

With these types:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME) @Target(TYPE) public @interface Haha {}

interface MyInterface<V>{}

@Haha public class StringImpl implements MyInterface<String> {}
```

Here's an annotation processor that prints "java.lang.String" for the `@Haha`annotation on `StringImpl`:

```
public class Proc extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton("bar.Haha");
    }

    @Override public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.RELEASE_8;
    }

    @Override public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                                     final RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Haha.class)) {
            if (element instanceof TypeElement) {
                TypeElement te = (TypeElement) element;
                for (TypeMirror typeMirror : te.getInterfaces()) {
                    if (typeMirror instanceof DeclaredType) {
                        DeclaredType dclt = (DeclaredType) typeMirror;
                        for (TypeMirror argument : dclt.getTypeArguments()) {
                            System.out.println(argument);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Getting there is a lot of testing and fiddling, and I used this test to debug the process:

```
public class ProcTest {
    @Test
    public void run() {
        String basePath = "/path/to/src/folder/";
        List<String> args = asList("Haha", "MyInterface", "StringImpl")
                .stream()
                .map(s -> basePath +"bar/" + s + ".java")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        args.addAll(0, asList("-processor", Proc.class.getName()));
        String[] flags = args.toArray(new String[3]);
        ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()
                    .run(System.in, System.out, System.err,  flags);
    }
}
```

If you run this in debug mode, you can set breakpoint inside the annotation processor. That really helped me understand things better.

Comment: Thanks but what about second or third way?

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi I gave you a starting point. You'll figure it out from there

Comment: Well if i get all ancestors for each element and get type arguments of their interfaces `System.out.println(argument);` will print `V` instead of `SomeClass`

Comment: Well then you'll have to create some code that recursively applies this logic to super classes and extended interfaces

Comment: I know, i already tried your approach but it doesn't work for ancestors. please see my edited question

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi this is an advanced topic and way out of scope for a stackoverflow question. I'm guessing providing a satisfactory solution would take a developer week. Have a look at the Guava link I posted in the comment above and see how they solved it at runtime in reflection. The abstractions are similar, perhaps you can re-use their approach.